# Geoserver memory issues

Tags: geoserver

There seems to be a few issues raised about geoserver's memory usage - I'm wondering if someone can speculate as to why my memory use is so high.

I'm currently running geoserver 2.11.1 under tomcat7 with a -Xms set to 8gb and -Xmx set to 12Gb. I have 45,000 layers containing small shapefiles (~3Mb each) across the same number of stores and around 60 workspaces.

Memory use, using the rest of the default values from tomcat and geoserver, immediately reaches 8Gb and I can't figure out why this would be the case.

Thoughts include:

1) Garbage collection is inefficient
2) There is a memory leak
3) There is not enough memory on the server

Hopefully someone can shine some light on why memory use is so high - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [`Xms`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-2180-10/pt_chap5.html) is the startup memory size, so it is expected that your application takes this amount of memory. Now let's not forget that it **reserves** this memory, it doesn't necessarily **use** it right away.